# Convert Price into Reward points

Tags: magento2, price, reward-points, magento-reward

I am working on Magento 2 Reward Points section and want to show price in points on storefront.

I have product price $25 on storefront And I have set Reward Exchange Rates

```
$1 = 10 points

10 points = 1$
```

Now the product price should be ( 250 points )

also currency symbols should show points instead of $

I am trying to achieve this from following method but stucks

```
class Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function convert($amount, $scope = null, $currency = null)
{
    $currentCurrency = $this->getCurrency($scope, $currency);

    return $this->getStore($scope)
        ->getBaseCurrency()
        ->convert($amount, $currentCurrency);
}
```

**Note: Price should be converted in points everywhere on store front.**

If you guys have any Idea please share

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Put some efforts at Least provide more description to question so that someone ca understand itt.

Comment: @Vivek I have update my question.

Comment: Hiya! 

Not a complete solution but might an idea. 

 1. Make a custom module
 2. Create needed functions that converts prices into points
 3. Create an override for templates, use your points conversion method

Comment: which issue you are facing?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I want to convert price  into reward points on store front if reward module is enabled.

Comment: I am asking what you have try and where you struct? Means actualy which error you are facing while try anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show price as points , You can implement following logic

- create a custom currency "Reward Points"
- Allow  "Reward Points" custom currency from admin panel currency
  settings
- Set currency set for "Reward Points" 10  = 1 USD
- set Default Display Currency to "Reward Points"

We accused Custom Currency code for Reward Points is "PTS" (as "INR" for Indian Rupee)

You can follow below steps to implement above logic.

**step 1)** 
open ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT-DIRECTORY/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml***

Under **currencies** xml entity , enter your custom currency entiry (i.e "Reward Points") as follows and save the xml file.

```
<currencies>
----------------
<currency type="PTS">
   <displayName>Reward Points</displayName>
   <displayName count="one">Reward Points</displayName>
   <displayName count="other">Reward Points</displayName>
   <symbol>points</symbol> 
</currency>
----------------
</currencies>
```

**step 2:**
open ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT-DIRECTORY/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml***

under **installed** XML entity enter your custom currency code
as below

```
<system>
<currency>
<installed>PTS,AZN,AZM,AFN,ALL,DZD,AOA,ARS,AMD,AWG,AUD,BSD,BHD,BDT,BBD,BYR,BZD,BMD,BTN,BOB,BAM,BWP,BRL,GBP,BND,BGN,BUK,BIF,KHR,CAD,CVE,CZK,KYD,CLP,CNY,COP,KMF,CDF,CRC,HRK,CUP,DKK,DJF,DOP,XCD,EGP,SVC,GQE,ERN,EEK,ETB,EUR,FKP,FJD,GMD,GEK,GEL,GHS,GIP,GTQ,GNF,GYD,HTG,HNL,HKD,HUF,ISK,INR,IDR,IRR,IQD,ILS,JMD,JPY,JOD,KZT,KES,KWD,KGS,LAK,LVL,LBP,LSL,LRD,LYD,LTL,MOP,MKD,MGA,MWK,MYR,MVR,LSM,MRO,MUR,MXN,MDL,MNT,MAD,MZN,MMK,NAD,NPR,ANG,TRL,TRY,NZD,NIC,NGN,KPW,NOK,OMR,PKR,PAB,PGK,PYG,PEN,PHP,PLN,QAR,RHD,RON,ROL,RUB,RWF,SHP,STD,SAR,RSD,SCR,SLL,SGD,SKK,SBD,SOS,ZAR,KRW,LKR,SDG,SRD,SZL,SEK,CHF,SYP,TWD,TJS,TZS,THB,TOP,TTD,TND,TMM,USD,UGX,UAH,AED,UYU,UZS,VUV,VEB,VEF,VND,CHE,CHW,XOF,XPF,WST,YER,ZMK,ZWD</installed>
</currency>
</system>
```

**step 3:** Create a custom extension or use any exiting custom extension

**step 4:** we assumed , we are using custom extension **Company_MyModule**

**step 5:** craete file **AddCurrencies.php** under **app/code/Company/MyModule/Model/Config**

File **AddCurrencies.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\MyModule\Model\Config;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\CurrencyBundle;

class AddCurrencies extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists
{

    public function getNewCurrencies() 
    {
        /* 
           This is your function that returns an array with new
           currencies. For example: 
         */
        return [
            ['value' => 'PTS', 'label' => 'Reward Points'],            
        ];
    }

    public function getOptionAllCurrencies()
    {
        $currencyBundle = new \Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\CurrencyBundle();
        $locale = $this->localeResolver->getLocale();
        $currencies = $currencyBundle->get($locale)['Currencies'] ?: [];

        $options = [];
        foreach ($currencies as $code => $data) {
            $options[] = ['label' => $data[1], 'value' => $code];
        }
        $options = array_merge($options, $this->getNewCurrencies());

        return $this->_sortOptionArray($options);
    }

    public function getOptionCurrencies()
    {
        $currencies = (new CurrencyBundle())->get($this->localeResolver->getLocale())['Currencies'] ?: [];
        $options = [];
        $allowed = $this->_config->getAllowedCurrencies();
        foreach ($currencies as $code => $data) {
            if (!in_array($code, $allowed)) {
                continue;
            }
            $options[] = ['label' => $data[1], 'value' => $code];
        }
        $options = array_merge($options, $this->getNewCurrencies());

        return $this->_sortOptionArray($options);
    }


}
```

**step 6:** Run following CLI command from your Magento 2 root directory to clear static contend and generated files

```
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/generated
```

**step 7:** Again run following CLI command from your Magento 2 root directory

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo chmod -Rv 777 pub var generated
```

**step 8:** Please go to admin panel and navigate **Stores->Configuration-> Currency Setup** (under general tab)
Select "**Reward Points**" and "**US Dollar**" as Allowed Currencies.
now click "**Save Config**" button.

**Step 9:** Please go to Admin panel **Stores-> Currency Rates**
Now enter Currency rate for "PTS" (i.e Reward Points) as 10.00 = 1 USD
click "**Save Currency Rates**"

**Step 10:** Refresh Cache from **System-> Cache Management**

**step 11:**  To display Price in Points,  Please go to admin panel and navigate **Stores->Configuration-> Currency Setup** (under general tab)
set
Default Display Currency =  Reward Points
click "Save Config"

**step 12:** Please refresh cache again to show price in Points

[image: Allowed Currency setting]

[image: Price With USD]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Pritam Info 24

I'm trying to Implement this but the Currency Reward Points doesn't show up in list of currencies..

This node was not present in my 
YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT-DIRECTORY/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml

```
 <system>
    <currency>
    <installed>PTS,AZN,AZM,AFN,ALL,DZD,AOA,ARS,AMD,AWG,AUD,BSD,BHD,BDT,BBD,BYR,BZD,BMD,BTN,BOB,BAM,BWP,BRL,GBP,BND,BGN,BUK,BIF,KHR,CAD,CVE,CZK,KYD,CLP,CNY,COP,KMF,CDF,CRC,HRK,CUP,DKK,DJF,DOP,XCD,EGP,SVC,GQE,ERN,EEK,ETB,EUR,FKP,FJD,GMD,GEK,GEL,GHS,GIP,GTQ,GNF,GYD,HTG,HNL,HKD,HUF,ISK,INR,IDR,IRR,IQD,ILS,JMD,JPY,JOD,KZT,KES,KWD,KGS,LAK,LVL,LBP,LSL,LRD,LYD,LTL,MOP,MKD,MGA,MWK,MYR,MVR,LSM,MRO,MUR,MXN,MDL,MNT,MAD,MZN,MMK,NAD,NPR,ANG,TRL,TRY,NZD,NIC,NGN,KPW,NOK,OMR,PKR,PAB,PGK,PYG,PEN,PHP,PLN,QAR,RHD,RON,ROL,RUB,RWF,SHP,STD,SAR,RSD,SCR,SLL,SGD,SKK,SBD,SOS,ZAR,KRW,LKR,SDG,SRD,SZL,SEK,CHF,SYP,TWD,TJS,TZS,THB,TOP,TTD,TND,TMM,USD,UGX,UAH,AED,UYU,UZS,VUV,VEB,VEF,VND,CHE,CHW,XOF,XPF,WST,YER,ZMK,ZWD</installed>
    </currency>
    </system>
```

Please help.